# How to Query Sublist in CosmosDB to desired output

Tags: json, azure, .net-core, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

```
{
  "Name": "Sam",
  "Car": [
    {
      "Brand": "BMW",
      "Category": "HunchBack",
      "Type": "Gas"
    },
    {
      "Brand": "Tesla",
      "Category": "Sedan",
      "Type": "Electric"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to Cosmos Sqlquery to query the sublist **CAR** on **BRAND** and it will only return those document that matches the criteria.

```
Select * from c JOIN t IN c.Car
where t.BRAND = 'Tesla'
```

I tried this but it only works partially, as it also return the Sublist **BMW**

**But expected output is**

```
{
  "Name": "Sam",
  "Car": [
    {
      "Brand": "Tesla",
      "Category": "Sedan",
      "Type": "Electric"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Any progress? If you have other problems, pls add details here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it?

```
Select distinct c.Name,ARRAY(SELECT n.Brand,n.Category,n.Type FROM n IN c.Car where n.Brand = 'benci') as Car from c JOIN t in c.Car where t.Brand='benci'
```

Comment: I want to use orderby with above query. But the OredrBy should only be on Name.Giving error while running from Function app

Comment: Good day sir! Exactly I'm not an expert in azure function, and I think you can ask another question with more details, there must be more people to see :). @Deepcoder

Comment: Due to some restriction i will not be able to use DISTINCT keyword. Is there any other approach to avoid duplicates

Comment: I'm afraid not. Here we need to use `join` to achieve subquery, it will lead to the subquery result and mainquery has a 'Cartesian product'? That means it will appear duplicates. And  cosmosdb doesn't offer any other funtions except `distinct` as I know. So I you mustn't use DISTINCT, I think you need to remove the duplicates in your backend code.